# How to add a background image with gradient border to UIImageView in swift?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

We have some UIImageViews that are 18 x 18.  We want a "background" behind it of a solid circle with a radius of 45.  Around that circle we want a gradient border from clear to white.

How can I pull that all off together?